# vs2010 and ajaxcontroltoolkit 4.0 issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0

I installed AjaxControlToolkit 4.0 and have been trying to use the extenders, but when I try to drag the controls to the HTML markup nothing shows up. Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave a suggestion and it is now disappeared all of the sudden. Using the extender menu worked like it should